# ksh, perform action when reaching loop maximal value

Tags: loops, ksh

I am looking to write a small korn shell script doing 5 tests (by waiting some time before each one) and then, if they all fail, performing an action.

I was looking at doing something like :

```
    for i in {1..5}
    do
       "doMyTest"             #it fills a variables "status" (but can unfortunately fails)
       if [ "$status" ]; then #if status is filled then we can leave the loop
          break
       fi
       sleep 3                #else wait some time before doing another try
    done

    if [ -z "$status" ]; then
       exit 1
    fi

... then the rest of my program
```

Do you have any idea how could I do this in a better way ? 
It sounds a bit redundant ...

Thank you very much.

Comment: won't it automatically leave the loop once all 5 iterations have happened (without hitting the `break` logic)? Else you need to explain your problem with example output. Maybe 2 examples showing the `break` being used and then another example without the `break` being used. Good luck.

Comment: It could be possible that the "doMyTest" does not always work and does not filled the variable status. I want to do it 5 times, if it works the first time by instance (status is filled) then it will do the break and leave. The next if won't be filled, exit 1 won't be called, and my program will go on. However, in the case value $status is not filled because "doMyTest" failed, I want to try it 5 times before leaving (without using the break), then it will go in the if below, and will apply the exit 1. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: There may be syntax errors I'm missing, but your code seems reasonable to your problem.  What evidence do you have that it is not working as required? Do you know and use shell's debug/trace feature with `set -vx`? This will show you each "statement" before it is executed (in this case, the whole body of the `while` loop), and then what is actually executed (with a leading `+` char). This way you can see your variable names, and then with the `+` lines, you can see what values have been substituted for the variables. You should be able solve your problem using this. Good luck!

Comment: Try not to post the same question on different SE sites.  The same question appears on [unix/linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131316/ksh-perform-action-when-reaching-loop-maximal-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to see a failure when all tests fail?
When you can skip the other tests when one test succeeds, you can use

```
test1 || sleep 3 && \
   test2 || sleep 3 && \
   test3 || sleep 3 && \
   test4 || sleep 3 && \
   test5 || exit 1
```